# Visibility of path names declared in \foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, intersections

## Buildup

### Basic setting

Using the intersection library,
I encountered some behaviour of path names
that I do not understand.
The following works in the intended way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=pos] (0, -1) -- (2, 1);
\draw[name path=neg] (0,  1) -- (2, -1);

\fill[name intersections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Looping into a problem

But I have multiple paths to intersect,
so lets change it up a bit:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=pos] (0, -1) -- (2, 1);
% Only change: A senseless “loop”
\foreach \i in {0} {
    \draw[name path=neg] (0, 1) -- (2, -1);
}

\fill[name intersections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This looks to me as if it should be completely equivalent,
but now I get error messages:

> Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `neg'. Perhaps you misspelt it. ...[red, name intersections={of=pos and neg}]
>   Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known. ...ections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1)

The circle is drawn anyway,
since pgf simply assumes the coordinates of `(intersection-1)` to be `(0, 0)`,
but this was not the behaviour I expected or hoped for.

### A strange workaround

By drawing anything afterwards,
we can get it to run smoothly again:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=pos] (0, -1) -- (2, 1);
\foreach \i in {0} {
    \draw[name path=neg] (0, 1) -- (2, -1);
}

% Only change: Senseless path of vanishing length
\path (5, -1);

\fill[name intersections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Question

I would like to know *why* this happens.

Solutions and workarounds are of interest, too,
but might be better suited as answers to this [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop),
even though the existing answers
are mostly concerned with the expansion of options.

## Non-Explanations

As the third variant works without any problems,
there is no general problem exporting path names out of loops,
even though [using `name path global` provides another workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/naming-paths-inside-a-tikz-foreach-loop).

I did not encounter the same behaviour when declaring nodes,
so this seems to be a rather specific problem
of the intersection library.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting observation. I guess to *really* understand that you need to look at `libraries/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex`. There you can find all sorts of `FIXME` statements and questions whether or not one needs to reset the path. Once you will have the choice to either rewrite this library or just to use `name path global`, which worked perfectly fine in all situations I needed it so far.

Comment: It's also curious that, if you move the `\path (5, -1);` into the loop, the error reappears.

Comment: @marmot I do not actually think that is curious. It seems to be a bug in the handling of the loop. There is no reason to assume that moving more stuff into the loop makes the list of path names update the same way pretty much any command after the loop seems to do.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the x-offset from my experiments into the question before posting. This is fixed now.

Comment: Well, you point out yourself that the analogous problem does not occur with other named objects such as nodes. So how am I to interpret " It seems to be a bug in the handling of the loop." then? My above comment is just to say that it is not sufficient to just execute an additional path somewhere, it needs to be outside of the loop. This seems to prevent workarounds that simply modify `name path` to just append an empty path.

Comment: @marmot I guess I do now see where you're coming from. My mental model of how it should work was different from yours (and probably wrong). In my mind I saw it going like this: New mechanic is implemented for path names -> loops are mishandled *by this mechanic* -> touching any path *after* the loop somehow works around this. From this standpoint it did not seem surprising but now I am inclined to agree with you instead.

Comment: Agreed. I really believe it is an interesting problem. However, in my opinion one may just use a workaround as long as it is not too inconvenient. Ti*k*Z has been around for quite some time now and works really well overall. I am afraid that, even if one is able to fix this, other working code may cease to work. Hence I personally would argue that one should just use the workarounds in this case. This does, of course, not imply anything negative on your nice question, I am just saying in this case it may be better to be pragmatic.

Comment: I would argue that the fix shouldn't work, and that it may stop working without warning after an update.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am interested in your reasoning.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tend to agree, but would also be interested in your reasoning.

Comment: @HermannDöppes - As Marmont pointed out, the code is full of FIXME kludges.  Those tend to be removed with major revisions.  Ar least I would.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yeah, I agree. But I rather would have expected the workaround to become unnecessary as opposed to non-functional as soon as those FIXMEs are tackled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is global vs local as suggested by @marmot in his comment.

The body of `\foreach` is executed in a group, so all paths named with `name path` (or the equivalent `name path local`) are supposed to be non accessible outside the group because they are defined with `\def` and not with `\gdef` (as is the case for `name path global`).

You can check that the problem is group related and not specific to `\foreach` in the following example where `typeout` is used to display to the console the "neg" path stored in `\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=pos] (0, -1) -- (2, 1);
    {
      \draw[name path=neg] (0,  1) -- (2, -1);
      \typeout{=== inside === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg}
    }
    \typeout{=== outside === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg}

    \fill[name intersections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where the output is

> ```
> === inside === : macro:->\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {0.0pt}{28.45274pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@linetotoken {56.90549pt}{-28.45274pt}
> === outside === : undefined
> ! Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `neg'. Perhaps you misspelt it.
> ```

**So what is happening when we add some path command outside of the group ?**

The TikZ library `intersections` redefine `\tikz@finish` that is executed at every tikz command and run the GLOBAL `\tikz@intersect@namedpaths` (which contains the definition of the last path) if there is no `name intersections` option. So any `\path` command outside the group redefine the last path in the current group.

**This is a bug.** Which is probably known because [we can see in the code](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/c610c2/tree/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex#l67) :

> ```
> % FIXME : it is reasonable to reset this globally as it is global
> % in its nature. But the reset instruction should be moved to
> % \endscope or something related. Resetting it here breaks the
> % manual
> ```

We can check all of this in the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=pos] (0, -1) -- (2, 1);
    {
      \draw[name path=neg] (0,  1) -- (2, -1);
      \typeout{=== inside, neg === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg}
    }
    \typeout{=== outside, before path === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg}
    \typeout{=== the tikz@intersect@namedpaths === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@namedpaths}
    \path;
    \typeout{=== outside, after path === : \meaning\tikz@intersect@path@name@neg}

    \fill[name intersections={of=pos and neg}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where the output is

> ```
> === inside, neg === : macro:->\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {0.0pt}{28.45274pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@linetotoken {56.90549pt}{-28.45274pt}
> === outside, before path === : undefined
> === the tikz@intersect@namedpaths === : macro:->\def \tikz@intersect@path@name@neg {\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {0.0pt}{28.45274pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@linetotoken{56.90549pt}{-28.45274pt}}
> === outside, after path === : macro:->\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {0.0pt}{28.45274pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@linetotoken {56.90549pt}{-28.45274pt}
> ```

**Conclusion**

The normal behavior is that if you name a path with `name path` inside a group (for example inside `\foreach`) it should not be available outside the group.
If you want to make it available outside the group you should use `name path global` instead (as indicated by @marmot in his commentary).

The fact that using a simple `\path` outside the group make last named path available in the current group is a bug.

**Comment:** Actually [this bug is already reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/285/).