# Named paths inside a tikz/pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-pic

I am trying to understand the naming behavior of paths inside a `pic` definition.  Consider the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{%
    path1/.pic={%
        \coordinate (-p) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        \draw[red, name path=-horz-fails] (-1,0.5) to (1,0.5);
        \draw[black, name path=-vert] (0,-1) to (0,1);
    };
}
\tikzset{%
    path2/.pic={%
        \draw[blue, name path=-horz] (-1,0) to (1,0);
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [name=p1] at (0, 0) {path1};
    \pic (p2) at (0, 0) {path2};
    \draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt) to (p1-p);
    %\draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz-fails}]
    %    (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this example, all four lines are correctly drawn.  Further, the uncommented intersection is correctly drawn; however, if I uncomment the second intersection, I get get the compiler error

```
! Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `-horz-works'. Perhaps you 
 misspelt it.
```

From my searches, I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446025/61112) and the associated [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/285/) from the answer.  As with that answer, the last path named in the `pic` is available outside the definition.  I thought this might be related, but I cloned the repository and tried compiling with the fix, but I still get the same result.  I also tried to use `name path ..`, but that did not make the path available in the main picture environment.

My question is: Is this a manifestation of the same bug?  If not, what are the naming rules for paths inside a `pic` definition?

I notice that the coordinate (`-p` here) inherits the `pic` name outside scope of the `pic` as I expected and I would like to reference the path in the same manner.

---

### Motivation

My ultimate goal is to draw a line to the intersection of two paths defined inside a generated `pic`.  I have some Python code that generates the lines of latitude and longitude along a sphere.  I would like to use the `pic` multiple times within a single picture; thus, I would like to refer to the paths with the parent `pic` name to compute only those intersections that will further what I am trying to show.  Since I am computing the paths, I could define the coordinates of the intersections, but I would like to let TikZ do the job and that seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `name path global`, which is made for this: "broadcast" paths outside environments such as scopes or pics.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{%
    path1/.pic={%
        \coordinate (-p) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        \draw[red, name path global=-horz-fails] (-1,0.5) to (1,0.5);
        \draw[black, name path global=-vert] (0,-1) to (0,1);
    };
}
\tikzset{%
    path2/.pic={%
        \draw[blue, name path global=-horz] (-1,0) to (1,0);
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [name=p1] at (0, 0) {path1};
    \pic (p2) at (0, 0) {path2};
    \draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt) to (p1-p);
    \draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz-fails}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have unique names, just prepend the names of the paths by the name of the `pic`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figname}[1]{\edef#1{\tikz@fig@name}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    path1/.pic={%
        \figname{\myname}
        \coordinate (-p) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        \draw[red, name path global=\myname-horz-fails] (-1,0.5) to (1,0.5);
        \draw[black, name path global=\myname-vert] (0,-1) to (0,1);
    };
}
\tikzset{%
    path2/.pic={%
        \figname{\myname}
        \draw[blue, name path global=\myname-horz] (-1,0) to (1,0);
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (p1) at (0, 0) {path1};
    \pic (p2) at (0, 0) {path2};
    \draw [name intersections={of=p1-vert and p2-horz}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt) to (p1-p);
    \draw [name intersections={of=p1-vert and p1-horz-fails}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(same output)

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried `name path global`.  Good call.  My problem with that solution is the name collision because I want to use the pic multiple times in a single picture.  Any thoughts on how to get around that?

Comment: @KeithPrussing I added a way to make the path names unique, they get prepended by the name of the `pic`, just like the coordinates get.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the immediate problem, and I guess I'll just have to dig into the intersection library to get more on the naming.

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick hack by simply put every path in a single pic.

This does not answer your question but ensures that you no longer have any mistakes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{%
    path1/.pic={%
        \coordinate (-p) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        \draw[red, name path=-horz-fails] (-1,0.5) to (1,0.5);
       % \draw[black, name path=-vert] (0,-1) to (0,1);
    },
        path3/.pic={%
        \coordinate (-p) at (-0.5,-0.5);
        %\draw[red, name path=-horz-fails] (-1,0.5) to (1,0.5);
        \draw[black, name path=-vert] (0,-1) to (0,1);
    },
    path2/.pic={%
        \draw[blue, name path=-horz] (-1,0) to (1,0);
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [name=p1] at (0, 0) {path1};
    \pic (p2) at (0, 0) {path2};
    \pic (p3) at (0,0) {path3};
    \draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt) to (p1-p);
    \draw [name intersections={of=-vert and -horz-fails}]
        (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]